# How do I parse columns in a CSV File in Ruby and store it as an array?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have the following CSV file:

```
Date,Av,Sec,128,440,1024,Mixed,,rule,sn,version

6/30/2010,3.40,343,352.0,1245.8,3471.1,650.7,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 342,-0.26%,-0.91%,1.51%,-0.97%
6/24/2010,3.40,342,352.9,1257.2,3419.5,657.1,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 341,0.23%,0.50%,-1.34%,0.67%
6/17/2010,3.40,341,352.1,1251.0,3466.1,652.7,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 340,7.77%,5.32%,9.04%,1.71%
6/14/2010,3.40,340,326.7,1187.8,3178.7,641.7,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 339,-0.88%,-0.34%,-0.95%,0.05%
6/11/2010,3.40,339,329.6,1191.9,3209.2,641.4,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 338,0.58%,0.51%,-1.83%,0.99%
6/11/2010,3.40,338,327.7,1185.8,3269.1,635.1,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 335,-0.40%,-0.44%,1.46%,-1.96%
6/11/2010,3.40,335,329.0,1191.0,3221.9,647.8,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 333,-6.83%,-4.70%,-7.04%,-0.32%
6/11/2010,3.40,333,353.1,1249.8,3465.8,649.9,Mbps,on,s-2.8.6-38,4.9.1-229,,vs. 332,2.53%,2.02%,1.71%,2.14%
```

and I want to parse columns 4, 5, 6 and 7 and have four arrays, on which I can do operations like create a line graph against time, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [Ruby CSV module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CSV.html) which ships with Ruby. Example:

```
require 'csv'
require 'pp'

file = File.open( 'bar.csv' )
CSV::Reader.create( file ).each do |row|
  pp row[4..7]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

why reinvent the wheel!

Use plugin [`fastercsv`](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html) or [`csv`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/CSV.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are spoiled for choice in parsing CSVs with Ruby, as there are options included in the standard lib, as well as easy home-brewed methods or Open Source libs.

You can start with the examples on "[How to parse CSV data with Ruby](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/246-How-to-parse-CSV-data-with-Ruby)", and that should point you in the direction for digging deeper.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the smarter_csv Ruby gem and use a :key_mapping to ignore unwanted input columns.

See:

https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv