# Ruby parse csv by header values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm working on a method to take a CSV file (with headers) and parse it using Ruby `CSV.parse`, however I only want to save specific columns.

The CSV looks like this:

```
NAME,SUPERNET_IP,POP_NAME,ADDRESS_BLOCK_START,ADDRESS_BLOCK_END,Service,ISP Service ID,WCC,DUNSID
Retail,186.43.168.0,text1,186.43.168.0,186.43.175.255,XYZ,XYZB00090095,Enabled,227015716
Retail,186.57.80.0,text2,186.57.80.0,186.57.87.255,XYZ,XYXB00090095,Enabled,227015716
```

and the only fields I want to keep are:

```
POP_NAME,ADDRESS_BLOCK_START,ADDRESS_BLOCK_END,WCC
```

Is there a way to parse in the CSV by specific header names, like:

```
mycsv = CSV.parse(csv_data, {:headers => true, (list of headers to keep here) })
```

This example is assuming `csv_data` is a string formed from the example CSV above.

As a stopgap I'm just converting the CSV into an array of arrays but it's not really what I'm after. I'd rather keep it as a CSV object.

```
myreturnedcsv = []
mycsv = CSV.parse(csv_data, {:headers => true, })
mycsv.each do |row|
  myreturnedcsv.push([row[2], row[3], row[4],row[7]])
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse columns in a CSV File in Ruby and store it as an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237734/how-do-i-parse-columns-in-a-csv-file-in-ruby-and-store-it-as-an-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try the `smarter_csv` gem / parser. This has ability to ignore "columns" in the input (delete columns) https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Comment: this seems like it'll work any idea if I can validate header values using it?

Comment: Use SmarterCSV.process with option :key_mapping. Documentation says that -> a hash which maps headers from the CSV file to keys in the result hash. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: just map any columns you don't want to `nil` in the :key_mapping hash

Answer (score 2):

Using only stdlib, you can operate with `CSV::Table` objects in column mode 
(instead of mixed mode which is the default). In column mode, iteration methods
will yield two element tuples containing the column name and an Array of values
for that column.

With that in mind, we could write something like:

```
# column names to keep
columns_to_keep = %w(POP_NAME ADDRESS_BLOCK_START ADDRESS_BLOCK_END WCC)

# get the data
mycsv = CSV.parse(csv_data, :headers => true)

# change to column mode, filter by column name and change back to default
# mode of operation
mycsv.by_col!.delete_if do |col_name, col_values|
  !columns_to_keep.include?(col_name)
end.by_col_or_row!
```

Last step is optional and is only to leave the table object in the default mode
in which we can iterate as usual (by row).

I don't actually know if this approach may suffer from perf/mem issues when
dealing with large data sets.

You can find more information about row/col/mixed access in the docs for [CSV::Table](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it doing some array slicing:

```
require 'csv'

csv_data = <<EOT
NAME,SUPERNET_IP,POP_NAME,ADDRESS_BLOCK_START,ADDRESS_BLOCK_END,Service,ISP Service ID,WCC,DUNSID
Retail,186.43.168.0,text1,186.43.168.0,186.43.175.255,XYZ,XYZB00090095,Enabled,227015716
Retail,186.57.80.0,text2,186.57.80.0,186.57.87.255,XYZ,XYXB00090095,Enabled,227015716
EOT

data = []
CSV.parse(csv_data) do |row|
  data << [ *row[2 .. 4], row[-2] ]
end

require 'pp'
pp data
```

Which returns:

```
[["POP_NAME", "ADDRESS_BLOCK_START", "ADDRESS_BLOCK_END", "WCC"],
["text1", "186.43.168.0", "186.43.175.255", "Enabled"],
["text2", "186.57.80.0", "186.57.87.255", "Enabled"]]
```

I let CSV return the headers, to make it easier to see what the code is doing. Turn the headers off using the normal `new` option.